# What are the differences array usage and bindParam usage during mysql data inserting?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am preparing mysql configuration settings using class. I am confused about it. I always use bindParam. It also possible to insert using array. I mean, what are the differences between array and bindparam.

eg array

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET
username  = :uname,
password = :upass,
email = :umail");
$insert = $query->execute(array(
  "upass" => "123456",
  "umail" => "user@user.com",
  "uname" => "username",
));
if ( $insert ){
$last_id = $db->lastInsertId();
}
```

eg

```
$stmt = $this -> db_conn -> prepare("INSERT into users(username, password) VALUES(:uname, :upass)");
    $stmt -> bindParam(':uname', $username);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':upass', $password);
    $stmt -> execute();
```

Comment: Code clarity. It is a stylistic choice only.

Comment: So, there are no anything about security or speed.

Comment: Nope, not at all. The parameters get bound either way.

Comment: I get it well now. Thank you.

Comment: You should note that if you use the execute approach, all values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR. With bindParam you can define the datatype...

Answer (score 0):

Desconsidering the fact that with `execute` you can't choose the data type (it's always `PDO::PARAM_STR`)  There's only a main difference between both (which is from core). [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is by reference while [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) isn't. [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) do internnaly the same thing as [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), but twice.

Internally (in C), `bindValue` [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1601) the same method which `execute` [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L465). The method name which is called is [really_register_bound_param](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L280).

On the other hand, `bindParam` [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1617) other method called [register_bound_param](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1529).

It means that `bindValue` calls the same method called by `execute` more than one time while bindParam calls a method to bind as a reference and only "really register" the param when `execute` is called.

Thinking about bind by reference, it's only possible using `bindParam`:

```
//fictional code
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:value)");
$stmt->bindParam(":value", $randomValue);

for($i = 0 ; $i < 1000; $i))
{    $randomValue = rand(1000,1000000);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Is it worthy? Perhaps while a `while` with a complex insert with multiples parameters could reduce the overhead with rebinding a new parameter or a big amount of them.